# Is the $K_1$-group of a compact subset of the plane free?

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory

Let $X$ be a compact subset of the complex plane. Is it true that $K_1(C(X)) = K^1(X)$ is a free abelian group? My only basis for thinking this is that it is true for a finite wedge of circles.

Comment: I believe the Hawaiian earring space is a counterexample. See Eda, K.; Kawamura, K. (2000), "[The singular homology of the Hawaiian earring](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/62/1/305)", *Journal of the London Mathematical Society* **62** (1): 305–310, doi:10.1112/S0024610700001071.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.logic.info.waseda.ac.jp/~eda/pdf/singular.pdf) though appears to imply that this is, in some weak sense, the only way that a counterexample can occur if we restrict ourselves to certain nice one-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @DanielRust Sorry, my knowledge of topology is rather bad. How are the singular homology and $K^1(X)$ related?

Comment: There is a strong correlation between $K$-theory and singular cohomology, namely $K^0(X)\cong \bigoplus_{n}H^{2n}(X)$ and $K^1(X)\cong \bigoplus_{n}H^{2n+1}(X)$ (there may need to be some conditions applied to $X$ here, I can't remember). And there are the usual correlations between homology and cohomology via the universal coefficient theorem and (though it's not applicable here) Poincaré duality.

Comment: @DanielRust Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't feel confident enough in the above to turn it into an answer, as much of it was based on memory, so I'd be happy if someone else wanted to turn it into a full answer.